# Find nearest resturant, coffee shop, and grocery store using google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am working in android sdk and using google maps api. I wanted to know if there is any way to find the nearest resturant or coffee shop or a grocery store from current  location of the user.

There are many apps available for this purpose but i want to code my own application for learning purpose.

Answer (score 2):

This may help, dont know if it works for android..

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Comment: do you know if there is any cod eexample available for this place api ?

Comment: this is simple web service request, so u dont need any great coding for this purpose(I am not a Android guy, though I am trying to be, otherwise I could have helped more), but there is a catch, This API requires you to obtain a key from google for using this API. You need to submit a form for this purpose and wait for client Id from google . Please read the doc at URL for more info. Its a long way to go actually...

Comment: yes i have red the documentation. They have limitations and there are changing it in comming days. So i think i should move to yahoo local search suggested by Itsik. anyways thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue making a Navigation program for Android.
I ended up using [Yahoo! Local Search](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/local/V3/localSearch.html) web service, it worked pretty well.

You should understand how web services work, but basically you make an HTTP GET request with the parameters, such as Location, Query (restaurant, coffee, etc) and other parameters, and you get a response as XML or JSON (your choice).

What you do with the results is up to you

**Additions:**
Yahoo Local Search results are default to XML.
This is an example of how to make the request in Android:

```
   public void doWebRequest()
   {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  

            String url = "http://local.yahooapis.com/LocalSearchService/V3/localSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=pizza&zip=94306&results=2";         
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

      HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);  
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
            SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
            handleResponse(reader.read(bis));
        } catch (Exception e) {
         System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    private void handleResponse(Document doc) {
 // doc is the XML response
    // process the results here
 }
```

Comment: Help on Yahoo or help with coding a request in android ?

Comment: Thanks Itsik for your msg, can you tell me how can i edit the search query at run time. I mean if i write coffee shop in text field the query should search coffee shops.

Comment: I want to get pizza-shops results by giving my current latitude and longitude but i dont know how to construct the query. And i dont know how to pass pizza-shop and longitude and latitude to yahoo local search query.

Comment: You need to change the URL, by updating the parameter values. Go to the Yahoo website i linked, and read which parameters are relevant to what you want to do

Comment: I have gone through the link. I know which parameters i have to add or update But it doesnt work by updating parameters. can you share some code for updating parameters? I have no idea how to update url? I have tried to search on google but didnt get any help.

Comment: You can't use `appid=YahooDemo` for your own queries. You need register with yahoo to get your own id and use it make a request.

Comment: http://local.yahooapis.com/LocalSearchService/V3/localSearch?appid=oB7BXKnV34HZ6ndQeu43zyBctmgKKLUaeuKKJnqLHcUtndYM8rwFOdhXRsesIALWgiJes6Q-&query=pizza&city=stockholm&zip=14152

Comment: can i use latitude and longitude rather than city and zip code in query?

Comment: Yes, you can use Lat/Lng, you need to set the `latitude` and `longitude` parameters instead of the location, but I think that your problem is that I don't know if this web service works in Sweden! :)

Comment: Itsik do u know any service which works in sweden? It doesnt work even within uk states. Will it work in europe if i buy it?

Comment: any suggestion itsik ?? do u know any web service which i can use in sweden?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for this in Android, sorry. There may be Web services you can use for this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any example that you can suggest as a tutorial or helping material.

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help..

Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=Cafe"));
startActivity(intent);