# WebServices for Resaturant Search

Tags: android, web-services

Does anyone know available webservices for searching Restaurants within specific area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Method 1)
```

Yahoo webservices. [This answer is adequate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404439/find-nearest-resturant-coffee-shop-and-grocery-store-using-google-maps-in-andro/4420709#4420709)

```
Method 2)
```

Google api.

> http://maps.google.com/maps?q=restaurant&mrt=yp&sll=lat,lon&output=kml

Where lat, lon is your location.

Parse the kml that you get using a SAX parser the you get a list of places to eat.